# Dynamic algroithm for doing something with maximum profit

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

The Problem is: Imagine a student has `n` projects and `m` hours to do the projects. He has to manage his time to get the maximum points that he can get.

By working 1 hour on each project he can catch different points.
For example by working one hour on project 1, he can get 2 point and if he work two hours on project 1 he can get 2.25 points.
Project 2 is different - by working 1 hour on project 2, he can get 1 point, but by working two hours on it he can catch 2.5 points.

Another Example:

m = 5 and n = 10. means that there are 5 projects and 10 hours time to do the projects.

```
projectnumber  hours to complete   1 hour work  2h work  3h work  4h work    
     1                3                1.5        2        2.25     _
     2                4                0.5        1.75     2        2.25
     3                3                2          2.25     2.5      _
     4                2                1          2        _        _
     5                5                1          2        2.5      3
```

What I could understand:

After thinking about this, I understood it's like job scheduling and maybe the best algorithm for this problem is a dynamic programming algorithm.

At first you should consider the first hour of projects. and sort it by profit descending.

```
2  1.5  1   1   0.5
```

After doing the first hour of project 3, you should add the second hour of project 3 to the list (9 hours remain).

```
1.5  1   1   0.5  0.25 (0.25 is for second hour of project 3)
```

And it should continue till the end of the 10 hours time that you have to do the projects.

But I'm sure this algorithm has some problems. One of them is that, maybe the second hour of a project causes you to catch a good point. So you can not just consider the first hour of projects.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That just sounds like a greedy algorithm to me, not DP.

Comment: Thanks for edit Dukeling. You mean it is like knapsack?!!

Comment: The algorithm you described sounds like [a greedy algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm), but you mentioned Dynamic Programming, so I thought I'd just point that. (But yeah, it rather sounds like the knapsack problem)

Comment: What if the points for the 4th hr of project 2 was 30?  With a budget of 10 hr the greedy algorithm will never get near it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems similar to the 0-1 knapsack problem :-

> 1. Total hours m is that knapsack capacity
> 2. consider each number of hours and corresponding points as an item weight and value
> 3. Maximize the points.

0-1 Knapsack problem as DP solution in pseudo polynomial time.

Formulation of problem for Nth project :-

```
Knapsack(N,M) = max(Knapsack(N-1,M),Knapsack(N-1,M-1)+Points[N][1]+Knapsack(N-1,M-2)+Points[N][2]......)
```

**Note:-** Points[N][k] = points earns by working k hours on project N

[Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: The DP approach may require a small modification... (e.g. you can't work the second hour without working the first hour).

Comment: Yes, the problem is your should do each project hour by hour.

Comment: @Dukeling no i donot think you need that modification if you consider number of hours and corresponding points as item in knapsack problem and that what i meant

Comment: Consider two projects that each takes two hours to do.. and you have 2 hours to get the best point. Project 1: hour1: 3 hour2: 3.5     Project2: hour1: 0.5 hour2: 5 .. so this algorithm fails

Comment: @SamanParser check formulation of problem solves your problem

Comment: @VikramBhat For this solution, are you separating the hours such that each hour is basically considered a different item in the knapsack, or are you combining all hours for a project into one item, or something else? If the prior, how are you ensuring that you don't just pick the second hour because it gives lots of points without picking the first? If the latter, you need to separate it, as you may only do a single hour for some project.

Comment: @Dukeling combining all hours into one project but considering only one of them